# Operations on groups in Snowpark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm applying a function on a grouped dataframe in Pandas.
Has anyone had to convert this into the Snowpark API.  If so, what were the functions you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is now an [applyInPandas](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.RelationalGroupedDataFrame.applyInPandas) which I found as good way to address these situations